# How to find any javascript code file destination in wordpress website file manager?

Tags: javascript

How to find highlighted text I mean javacript file location in my wordpress website file manager. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLHBa.png)

I Can't resolve this problem and this thing cause to my website as I could't change anything with my site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.